# NTP client reseting date to 1970

Tags: ntp, ntpd, ntpdate

I have and debian running NTP client, but this cliente is reseting date to 1970.....and doesn't show any error in log.
This is that I tried:
1) date (shows 1970)
2) stop NTP service
3) ntpdate with server as parameter (date/time sync perfect)
4) date (show me correct date/time)
5) ntpd -q (reset date to 1970 without any error :/   )

This is my log fo these procedures....I don't have any idea how to fix this, since there's no error.

```
root@radarboxcomstation:~# date
Thu Jan  1 00:01:57 UTC 1970
root@radarboxcomstation:~# ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org
17 Jul 13:33:44 ntpdate[11163]: step time server 195.22.17.7 offset 1500298282.181552 sec
root@radarboxcomstation:~# date
Mon Jul 17 13:33:47 UTC 2017
root@radarboxcomstation:~# ntpd -q
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: ntpd 4.2.8p2@1.3265 Sun May 10 14:06:45 UTC 2015 (1): Starting
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: Command line: ntpd -q
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: proto: precision = 1.542 usec (-19)
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 10.161.68.1:123
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 [fe80::16ee:9dff:fe00:118%2]:123
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: authreadkeys: file /etc/ntp/keys: No such file or directory
restrict default: KOD does nothing without LIMITED.
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: restrict default: KOD does nothing without LIMITED.
restrict ::: KOD does nothing without LIMITED.
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: restrict ::: KOD does nothing without LIMITED.
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: switching logging to file /var/log/ntp.log
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: DNS 0.pool.ntp.org -> 194.8.30.16
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: DNS 1.pool.ntp.org -> 5.135.59.152
17 Jul 13:33:51 ntpd[11165]: DNS 2.pool.ntp.org -> 80.172.224.24
 1 Jan 00:00:00 ntpd[11165]: ntpd: time set -1500298431.132100 s
ntpd: time set -1500298431.132100s
root@radarboxcomstation:~# date
Thu Jan  1 00:00:03 UTC 1970
root@radarboxcomstation:~#
```

Comment: What show the command `ntpq -c peers localhost` when ntpd service is running?